# How to use multiple AND conditions in list comprehensions in python?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have this code where it takes 2 lists as input and prints 3rd list having common elements of both without duplicates.

One approach is the commented for loop which works fine and gives expected result. I am trying to achieve it with list comprehension but it gives duplicates.

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
c=[]
# for i in a:
#     if i in b and i not in c:
#         c.append(i)

c = [i for i in a if i in b and i not in c ]
print c
```

Expected result: 
    [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]

Current result with duplicates using list comprehension:
    [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]

I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A list cannot query itself while it is being built inside a list comprehension. The condition `i not in c` will always query the same value of `c` (the empty list `[]`) at the point just before the execution of your list comp, so your code is not aware of what was inserted in the last iteration during the next one.

---

**Option 1**

If order does not matter, you could just perform a `set` intersection:

```
c = set(a) & set(b)
print(list(c))
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13] # Warning! Order not guaranteed
```

---

**Option 2**

If order matters, use a `for` loop:

```
c = []
b = set(b)   
for i in a:
     if i in b and i not in c:
         c.append(i)

print(c)
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

---

**Option 3**

A slightly faster version of the above which retains order thanks to the use of an `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

b = set(b)
c = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys([i for i in a if i in b]).keys())
print(c)
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```